# Is information only about financial transactions personally identifiable in terms of GDPR?

Tags: privacy, gdpr

I am creating application where you can manage your incomes/expenses e.g. on eBay. Main functionality is:

1. create new item and specify price you've payed to get it
2. set price that you've

All other information is derived from this like monthly profit, statistics of sold item categories etc.

This is Android application, so user will install it from Google Play. Information will only be stored on user device. Possibly in the future it could be exported to device memory and user could share it on own will.

**Is this information classified as personally identifiable in therms of GDPR (like finance related)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the information is only stored on the user's own device, and never transmitted back to your application's host site, i don't think there is any GDPR issue even if the info includes personally identifiable information (PII).

In any case it isn't PII unless the user's name, IP address, or something else that could reasonably be used to identify the user is included. If it is just a list of items purchased and prices paid, i don't think that IDs the user. If you added postal code or other location info, or of course a name, it might be.